# Summary self-answer - close as multiple dup or links?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Should question created solely as navigation guide (somewhat canonical) to be closed as duplicate of many or provide answer with links to specific topics(as CW) or have real answer (and possibly duplicate all related once to it)?

Why: I've wrote [What question mark means in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075113/what-question-mark-means-in-c-sharp-code) which is obviously "no-research shown/clear duplicate" post strictly to solve search issue that at least on of common question mark usages is not searchable. I've provided CW answer and closed as duplicate of 4 questions.

I considered to provide actual answer (like [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)) but collection of MSDN links does not sound very good example of SO answer.

Comment: My opinion would be to improve the answer so that the question can be used as a canonical dupe target, just like the NRE one is used. Then we dupe the numerous questions out there to this one.